# How to Save Table as an Image (jpg)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, webkit

I want to save table as an image.I want to save the first row (first row contain image and text on that image)in the table as an image. e.g-jpg.

I used canvas but image was not too clear and I heard about the Webkit but,I don't know how to use it.

I am trying to make an android application (using phonegap).

I want to save the table as an image and save that image to the device (phone).

plz help me!

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- omitting link,meta & script -->
<!-- omitting link,meta & script -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textinput1').keyup(function () {
    $('#display').text($(this).val());
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
    cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>

        <!-- 1 row!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
        <tr>
             <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">

                <div class='wrapper'> 
                <img class="image_set"
                src="./img/old_coca_cola_bottles-wallpaper-1440x900.jpg"> 
                <div class='description'>  
                <p id="display" class='description_content'>text</p>  
                </div>  
                </div>  

             </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1 row end!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
     <!-- omitting below -->
     <!-- omitting below -->
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```